# 16.04 unstable wifi

Tags: networking, 16.04, intel-wireless

I'm having trouble with a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. My wireless card is the Intel Centrino Ultimate-N 6300. What I'm seeing is frequent packet loss and extreme latency (when idle, but especially when the interface is under load).

iwconfig shows that the card is connected at 81 Mb/s, but running iperf3 to a local server on the wired network, I get less than 5 Mb/s. Running Windows 10 on this same laptop, I easily sustained 150 Mb/s + with no packet loss.

I have tried several of the suggestions I have seen around, such as adding 11n_disabled=1 and 11n_disabled=8 (together and separately) and coex_active=0 to my iwlwifi.conf and rebooting. I have had mixed results with this, but all combinations resulted in either slow stable speed, or high speed with high packet loss.

I frequently use my laptop for working with large files, so the extra speed is critical. Has anyone else seen this on 16.04? Please see the attached image which shows the latency spikes and missing sequence #s.

[image: ping screenshot]

*edited for correct version # (was listed as 16.06, not 16.04)

Comment: I am actually having the same problem.